# Late 2000s show similar to Power Rangers, with kids in space and a bad alien cat

Tags: story-identification, tv

My memory of this show is quite hazy now as it was such a long time ago. I'm sure it aired somewhere between 2005 and 2008.

I used to think it was a version of *Power Rangers* but it's not; it's something similar, though. It's about kids traveling through space in a ship to save the Earth. I think the leader was a girl and they had uniforms that were similar to *Power Rangers*.

I think the bad guy was an alien cat, and I'm sure they had a dog, though I can't remember if it could talk.

Comment: https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Yale_of_Saard matches for an alien cat Power Ranger, but that's the comic.

Comment: So the bad guy was a cat and the good guys maybe had a dog?

Comment: If it's the bad guy, I suppose not [Kat Manx](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Kat_Manx) from *Power Rangers SPD*?

Comment: *Los Luchadores* had an evil **dog** as the villain...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots If Kat Manx is the cat, Commander "Doggie" Cruger would be the talking dog.

Comment: And V.R. Troopers was quite like Power Rangers, with the good guys having a talking pet dog.

Comment: *Power Rangers in Space* did have the Rangers "travelling through space in a ship to save the Earth".